# Does Nexus Repository Manager support "Used By" queries?

Tags: nexus

I need to search for all artifacts among my projects that require a particular dependency. Mvnrepository.com has such a feature, so I checked whether Nexus Repository Manager supported it as well.

I did not find any such feature, so I decided to come ask here, seeing as I usually don't do well with Nexus documentation or interface.

Does it support it?

I'll ask whether there are other tools that might do so in a separate question.